# How to Copy one folder local file to SFTP server using PHP

Tags: php

This is my code to send single file from local to SFTP server. Single file successfully send.
I want to send one folder from local to SFTP server , but i dont know how to send one folder. i need help

```
<?php
    $src = 'xxxxxxx';
    $filename = 'test.txt';
    $dest = 'xxxxxxxx'.$filename;

    // set up sftp ssh-sftp connection
    $connection = ssh2_connect('xxxxxx', 22);
    ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');

    // Create SFTP session
    $sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection);

    $sftpStream = @fopen('ssh2.sftp://'.$sftp.$dest, 'w');

    try {
        if (!$sftpStream) {
            throw new Exception("Could not open remote file: $dest");
        }
        $data_to_send = @file_get_contents($src);

        if ($data_to_send === false) {
            throw new Exception("Could not open local file: $src.");
        }      
        if (@fwrite($sftpStream, $data_to_send) === false) {
            throw new Exception("Could not send data from file: $src.");
        } else {
            //Upload was successful, post-upload actions go here...
        } 
        fclose($sftpStream);                   
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        error_log('Exception: ' . $e->getMessage());
        fclose($sftpStream);
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

ssh2_scp_send in php looks like just support sending file.
maybe these ways work:

```
1.compress folder, send the compressed file
2.use ssh2 to mkdir, then send each file iteratively
3.try with system() function to excute cmd line order "scp -r folder_path user@host:target_path"
```